# Typescript Command pattern return type

Tags: typescript, command-pattern

Below is command pattern where you have a Command and a Handler for a command, they get added to the `CommandBus` and then executed there when called upon. The command has a type in this case `<string>` that I want to be returned when executing the Command in the `CommandBus`

The issue is the last line `var whatIsThis = CommandBus.execute<string>(new GetStringCommand("Hello, world"));` more specifically I want to remove  form that statement because it should come from the `Command`. The `CommandBus` class should know it should return  from `class GetStringCommand implements Command<string>`.

```
interface Command<T> {
    name:string;
}

class GetStringCommand implements Command<string> {
    public str:string;
    public name:string = "GetStringCommand";
    constructor(str:string){
        this.str = str;
    }
}

interface CommandHandler<T> {
    execute(command:Command<T>): T;
}

class GetStringHandler implements CommandHandler<string> {
    execute(command:GetStringCommand):string {
        return command.str;
    }
}

interface CommandRegistry {
    [x:string]: CommandHandler<any>
}

class CommandBus {
    private static actions:CommandRegistry = {};

    static add(name:string, command:CommandHandler<any>) {
        CommandBus.actions[name] = command;
    }

    static execute<T>(command:Command<T>) : T {
        return CommandBus.actions[command.name].execute(command);
    }
}

CommandBus.add("GetStringCommand", new GetStringHandler());

var whatIsThis = CommandBus.execute<string>(new GetStringCommand("Hello, world"));
```

The solution above is valid and works fine, however it's a terrible solution because it makes refactoring painful, and it makes me have to repeat myself over and over again since I'll use thousands of commands.

**Actual example**
Here's an example of a command handler that saves a schema in MongoDB, the same command could be utilized for creating a schema in MySQL

```
export class SaveSchemaCommandHandler implements CommandHandlerBase<void> {
    execute(command:SaveSchemaCommand) {
        var db = MongoConnection.db;
        var collectionOptions = { autoIndexID: true };

        db.createCollection(command.schema.getName(), collectionOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the handlers at all? Can't you just have `execute` in `Command`?

Comment: Separation of concerns. The idea is that one command can be utilized by multiple command handlers, for example, for a save action and you have  multiple database systems, those databases would then each have a command handler to perform that operation (and they'll essentially become plug and play), you don't need to write one giant command for all databases, and well, if you want to customize what databases you want to use, well.. it would simply be impossible without the handlers

Comment: If you have different DBs then you need different commands in order to use them. Unless I'm missing something in your design, it seems that the handler is just a wrapper for the command which returns the value. Maybe you can include a more interesting example in your code?

Comment: See an example above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand your handlers are the real commands, while what you call command is simply the params that the handler needs in order to execute.

You can replace your "commands" with simple interfaces, and your handlers become the commands.
You can then remove the need for classes for these new commands because you can just pass the execute function as the command.

Something like this:

```
interface CommandData {}

interface GetStringCommandData extends CommandData {
    value: string;
}

interface SaveSchemaCommandData extends CommandData {
    schema: { name: string };
}

type Command<In extends CommandData, Out> = (data: In) => Out;

interface CommandRegistry {
    [x: string]: Command<CommandData, any>;
}

class CommandBus {
    private static actions:CommandRegistry = {};

    static add(name: string, command: Command<CommandData, any>) {
        CommandBus.actions[name] = command;
    }

    static execute<T>(name: string, data: CommandData) : T {
        return CommandBus.actions[name](data);
    }
}

CommandBus.add("GetStringCommand", (data: GetStringCommandData) => data.value);
CommandBus.add("SaveSchemaCommand", (data: SaveSchemaCommandData) => {
    let db = MongoConnection.db;
    let collectionOptions = { autoIndexID: true };

    db.createCollection(data.schema.name, collectionOptions);
});

CommandBus.execute("GetStringCommand", { value: "my string" });
CommandBus.execute("SaveSchemaCommand", { schema: { name: "mySchema" } });
```

It seems simpler and easier to maintain, but I'm not sure if it fits all your needs.

---

#### Edit

It's not as trivial to get the right type from the execute operation, but you have a few options:

(1) Using a return type generics in `CommandData`:

```
interface CommandData<T> {}

interface GetStringCommandData extends CommandData<string> {
    value: string;
}

class CommandBus {
    ...

    static execute<T>(name: string, data: CommandData<T>): T {
        return CommandBus.actions[name](data);
    }
}

let str: string = CommandBus.execute("GetStringCommand", { value: "my string" } as CommandData<string>);
```

(2) Using `any`:

```
class CommandBus {
    ...

    static execute(name: string, data: CommandData): any {
        return CommandBus.actions[name](data);
    }
}

let str: string = CommandBus.execute("GetStringCommand", { value: "my string" });
```

(3) Declaring the possible signatures for the execute:

```
class CommandBus {
    ...

    static execute(name: "GetStringCommand", data: GetStringCommandData): string;
    static execute(name: "SaveSchemaCommand", data: SaveSchemaCommandData): void;
    static execute(name: string, data: CommandData): any;
    static execute(name: string, data: CommandData): any {
        return CommandBus.actions[name](data);
    }
}

let str: string = CommandBus.execute("GetStringCommand", { value: "my string" });
```

This option isn't very scaleable, but it's still an option.

Comment: Replacing the commands with interfaces is a good idea I think, because they only contain structure, there's an issue with the return type above though: `var xyz:string = CommandBus.execute("GetStringCommand", { value: "my string" });` would give the error **"Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'"** you can pass in <string> before but I'd like to avoid that

Comment: I think this solution is good enough, the functions have to be classes because they contain more then an execute normally, thanks for the help!

Comment: Check my revised answer, I gave you 3 options of how to deal with that.

Comment: @NitzanTomer in your 1st example,  when executing the command, I'd pass in `GetStringCommandData` instead of the base `CommandData<string>`. But the return type inference for the generic seems to get lost and becomes `{}`. Is there a way to get around this without including the generic in the `GetStringCommandData`?

Comment: @ShawnMclean I guess that you can use [Type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)

Comment: @NitzanTomer the solution was a bit more hacky, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291038/400861