# Typescript generic inference from interface implementation

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to infer the return type of a method from the generic of an argument passed in. However, the argument is an implementation from a generic interface, so I would assume typescript inferencing would have determined the type from the argument's base.

Example code:

```
interface ICommand<T> {}

class GetSomethingByIdCommand implements ICommand<string> {
  constructor(public readonly id: string) {}
}

class CommandBus implements ICommandBus {
  execute<T>(command: ICommand<T>): T {
    return null as any // ignore this, this will be called through an interface eitherway
  }
}

const bus = new CommandBus()
// badResult is {}
let badResult = bus.execute(new GetSomethingByIdCommand('1'))

// goodResult is string
let goodResult = bus.execute<string>(new GetSomethingByIdCommand('1'))
```

What I'd like to do is the first `execute` call and have typescript infer the correct return value, which is `string` in this case based on what `GetSomethingByIdCommand` was implemented from.

I've tried playing around with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) but not sure if this is a solution or how to apply it.

Comment: Perhaps the problem here is that there are no restrictions on your `ICommand<T>` interface in regards to how `T` is used. Because of that, your `GetSomethingByIdCommand` class *also implicitly implements* `ICommand<number>` (for example). Indeed it seems that the class is an implementation of `ICommand<T>` *for any type `T`*. Given that, how is TypeScript to choose which type to infer?

Comment: @CRice I don't quite understand this. How does `GetSomethingByIdCommand` implicitly implement `ICommand<number>` when it explicitly implements `ICommand<string>`? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that `ICommand<T>` is not structurally dependent on `T` (as mentioned in [@CRice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6293409/crice)'s comment).

This is [not recommended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot---).  (⬅ link to a TypeScript FAQ entry detailing a case that is almost exactly the same as this one, so that's as close to an official word as we're likely to get here)

TypeScript's type system is (mostly) structural, not nominal: two types are the same if and only if they are the same shape (e.g., have the same properties) and it has nothing to do with whether they have the same name.  If `ICommand<T>` isn't *structurally* dependent on `T`, and none of its properties have anything to do with `T`, then `ICommand<string>` is the *same type* as `ICommand<number>`, which is the same type as `ICommand<ICommand<boolean>>`, which is the same type as `ICommand<{}>`.  Yes, those are all different *names*, but the type system isn't nominal, so that doesn't count for much.

You can't rely on type inference to work in such cases.  When you call `execute()` the compiler tries to infer a type for `T` in `ICommand<T>`, but there's nothing from which it can infer.  So it ends up defaulting to the empty type `{}`.

The fix for this is to make `ICommand<T>` structurally dependent in some way on `T`, and to make sure any type that implements `ICommand<Something>` does so correctly.  One way to do this given your example code is this:

```
interface ICommand<T> { 
  id: T;
}
```

So an `ICommand<T>` must have an `id` property of type `T`.  Luckily the `GetSomethingByIdCommand` actually does have an `id` property of type `string`, as required by `implements ICommand<string>`, so that compiles fine.

And, importantly, the inference you want does indeed happen:

```
// goodResult is inferred as string even without manually specifying T
let goodResult = bus.execute(new GetSomethingByIdCommand('1'))
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Great answer. This is certainly not very intuitive if you're coming from a different language that supports generics, like Java for instance.

Comment: Also, if you are in a situation where you cannot rely on having a value for your tag property (in the above, `id`), you can define it as a member and use the definite assignment operator to avoid having to set it: `id!: string`;

Comment: @y2bd could you explain this a bit more? I had issues using it in the interface, so I ended up using `id?: string` that also applied to the class implementation.

Comment: @ShawnMclean Here is an example: https://repl.it/repls/WoozyStupidAtoms

Answer (score 2):

Typescript seems to be able to correctly infer the type if the concrete type is coerced into its generic equivalent before it is passed to `ICommandBus.execute()`:

```
let command: ICommand<string> = new GetSomethingByIdCommand('1')
let badResult = bus.execute(command)
```

Or:

```
let badResult = bus.execute(new GetSomethingByIdCommand('1') as ICommand<string>)
```

This isn't exactly an elegant solution, but it works. Clearly typescript generics are not very feature complete.

Answer (score 1):

TS cannot infer the interface that method is implementing in the way you want it to.

What is happening here is that when you instantiate a new class with:

```
new GetSomethingByIdCommand('1')
```

The result of instantiating a new class is an object. For that reason `execute<T>` will return an object instead of the string that you expect.

You will need to do the type check after execute function returns a result.

In the case of object vs string, you can just do a typeof check.

```
const bus = new CommandBus()
const busResult = bus.execute(new GetSomethingByIdCommand('1'));
if(typeof busResult === 'string') { 
    ....
}
```

This works fine at runtime, when typescript is compiled to just plain JS.

In case of objects or arrays (which are also objects :D), you would use a type guard.

Type guard tries to cast an item to something and checks if a property exists and infers what model was used.

```
interface A {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface B {
  id: string;
  value: number;
}

function isA(item: A | B): item is A {
  return (<A>item).name ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: What the question really asks is how to make the type inference work in an intuitive way. `badResult` is expected to have `string` type because the `execute()` is given an object  which implements `ICommant<T>` and `T` is bound to `string`...

Comment: Unfortunately TS inferrence is a bit limited in that scenario. You cannot infer the implemented interface in that way. Result of instantiating a new class is always an object, so the return type is inferred as an object for that reason.